# Prod Order - Job Card report

Tags: dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

one of the customer is testing a report, the Prod Order - Job card and when they click on preview its blank, if they click Print-> PDF it does nothing.. this is all happening under one company only. if they do the same steps under another company it works fine, any ideas why?

Comment: What does debugger shows?

Comment: Is there a difference between the company logo sizes (see 'Company Information').
Other than that, the status of the job may be different?  One is already archived (production orders are archived when their status has been changed from Released to Finished).  
Finally, it may be possible to change the report ID that works with the Production Order.